# updateChildren() removes the old data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Firebase DB has structure like this:

```
user
-    userId
     -    pics
          -    "key1" - "url1"
          -    "key2" - "url2"
```

Now I want to add a new picture to the same user. So I am using updateChildren().

```
HashMap<String, String> paths = new HashMap<>();
paths.put("/user/<userId>/pics/key3", "url3");
dbRef.updateChildren(paths);
```

Since there is no "key3", so the expectation is it should add a new node with new value. But instead of adding, it deletes the old nodes too. So at the end of this execution, I have only one pic instead of 3.

I know we can solve this using transaction, but for that we need to download the whole data to client and re-upload it. Any alternative to do it without transaction?

Moreover, transactions are to avoid synchronous update of sme child, since I don't have any child "user-userId-pics-key3", it should not have any problem solving it without transaction.

Comment: Please share your code. How do you instantiate dbRef?

Comment: dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

Comment: My mistake. This seems working fine. The problem was because of some other part of the code.

Comment: @ChandraSekhar i am having a similar problem here https://stackoverflow.com/q/56142170/3904109 can you please share what other part of code was creating a problem?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran this minimal code snippet based on yours:

```
DatabaseReference dbRef = database.getReference("46503277");
HashMap<String, Object> paths = new HashMap<>();
paths.put("pics/key3", "url3");
dbRef.updateChildren(paths);
```

And it added `key3` to the existing `key1` and `key2` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/46503277.json)). If that is not happening for you, something else must be going on.

Comment: Seems like my code is similar to ours. How does it work for you? The c=only change is, you are putting "pics/key3" as pics is root node. Where as I am putting "user/userId/pics/key3" as it is part of pics inside user node.

Comment: I also had to change the type definition of the `HashMap`, because with your code I couldn't pass `paths` to `updateChildren()`.

Answer (score 0):

`updateChildren` updates all the child nodes. Hence when there is no value, it is updated with `null`. You may use `setValue()` method here.

```
dbRef.child("/user/<userId>/pics/key3").setValue("url3");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
mDatabase.child("user").child(userId).child("pics").child("key3").setValue("url3");
```