# Update Multiple Fields in Multiple Nodes Simultaneously in Firebase (Android)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to update multiple fields in different nodes using Maps and Update children however firebase is deleting the data in the respective nodes and adding the data. I want the data to be updated and previous data to remain the same.  Interestingly the logic works while updating 2 fields in the same node, but not when multiple nodes are introduced. Please see the code below.

I am not trying to create new fields, but merely update 2 existing fields each in 2 different nodes simultaneously.  Each nodes has 10 different fields which I want to keep.

I am calling this from inside a viewholder.button (in a recycler view adapter)

```
String ref1 = "users/" + currentUserId;
String ref2 = "user_detail_profile/" + currentUserId;

HashMap<String, Object> updateFbDb1 = new HashMap<>();
updateFbDb1.put("name", "Albert Einstein");
updateFbDb1.put("score", 23);

HashMap<String, Object> updateFbDb2 = new HashMap<>();
updateFbDb2.put("claps", 55);
updateFbDb2.put("comments", 21);

HashMap<String, Object> updateFbDb3 = new HashMap<>();

updateFbDb3.put(ref1, updateFbDb1);
updateFbDb3.put(ref2, updateFbDb2);

fbDbRefRoot.updateChildren(updateFbDb3);
```

**This is working but I would like to do it in one shot so a success listener can be attached on all or none basis.**

```
HashMap<String, Object> updateFbDb1 = new HashMap<>();
updateFbDb1.put("name", "Albert Einstein");
updateFbDb1.put("score", 23);

HashMap<String, Object> updateFbDb2 = new HashMap<>();
updateFbDb2.put("claps", 55);
updateFbDb2.put("comments", 21);

fbDbRefRoot.child("users").child(currentUserId).updateChildren(updateFbDb1);
fbDbRefRoot.child("user_detail_profile").child(currentUserId).updateChildren(updateFbDb2);
```

Comment: you are using realtime db or firestore ?

Comment: realtime database

Comment: great let me help you with my answer. 

   you should use firebase push method to add new data

Comment: this is not new data it is just updating some fields

Comment: right right I thought you want new row

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following solution is working based on @Alex Mamos suggestion is working...

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("/users/" + currentUserId + "/name/", "Albert Einstein");
map.put("/users/" + currentUserId + "/score/", 23);
map.put("/user_detail_profile/" + currentUserId + "/claps/", 45);
map.put("/user_detail_profile/" + currentUserId + "/comments/", 8);
fbDbRefRoot.updateChildren(map);
```

Somehow inserting maps inside maps does not work.  It all has to be a part of a large map.

Comment: now a success listener can be added and it will update as a batch.

Comment: its working for me. Thanks to both Alex and DragonFire

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying to update multiple fields in different nodes using Maps and Update children however firebase is deleting the data in the respective nodes and adding the data.

This is happening when you are using DatabaseReference's [setValue(Object value)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#setValue(java.lang.Object)):

> Set the data at this location to the given value.

Going forward,

> I want the data to be updated and previous data to remain the same.

In this case, you should use DatabaseReference's [updateChildren(Map update)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#updateChildren(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%3E)), I see you are already using it in your code.

> Update the specific child keys to the specified values.

Going even further,

> This is working but I would like to do it in one shot so a success listener can be attached on all or none basis.

In this case, you should use batch operations, as explained in my answer from the follwing post:

- [Firebase - How to delete many entries at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45284468/firebase-how-to-delete-many-entries-at-once/45285242)

You can now add a complete listener or a success listener to the batch operation. Please also note, that is an atomic operation, which means that either all of the operations succeed, or none of them are applied.

Comment: Hi Alex, I am thankful for the time you put in to give an answer, but is it possible to give some working code to show what works.  Theoretically the first code in my question should work but it is not working.

Comment: please see my answer it seems the update children works when all the nodes are entered into the map as a single large map, rather than maps inside maps... its spooky.

Comment: I cannot code for you. Generally speaking, you should make your own attempt given the informations in the answer and ask another question if something else comes up. Beside that, your answer is an exact **duplicate** of the solution that is linked in my answer above and I have added it especially to help you. So what you did, is copy my answer and put it in your answer. Hope you'll make it right :)

Comment: Hi Alex your answer is similar but not exact.  My case involves two fields in each node.  You have only one field in each node.  Secondly I did make an attempt by trying to add maps inside maps.  My answer will demonstrate that that does not work and the correct approach is to make one large map.  This will help many other users in a way your answer will not.  I could have simply not posted anything because I am not getting any points by marking my own answer correct.  The goal is to give back something to stackoverflow after receiving so much.

Comment: PS I have given credit to you in my answer below, and I am thankful to you for helping me.

Comment: @DragonFire It's almost impossible to find a perfect match between answers. Yes, it's similar and that's why similar answers are usually marked as duplicates. When someone shows you an example, for sure you won't find the same names or number for the properties, the idea and the solution must be the same but it's up to you to decide which answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there you can use push method while adding data to firebase node

Here is how you create instance

```
    private lateinit var database: DatabaseReference
    // ...
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
```

This is how you simply add data

```
    mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).child("username").setValue(name);
```

And this is how you push data

```
    String key = mDatabase.child("posts").push().getKey();
    Post post = new Post(userId, username, title, body);
    Map<String, Object> postValues = post.toMap();

    Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
    childUpdates.put("/posts/" + key, postValues);
    childUpdates.put("/user-posts/" + userId + "/" + key, postValues);

    mDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates);
```

Also if you want to update specific filed

Here is a Link

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields

Comment: I am not trying to create new fields, but merely update 2 existing fields each in 2 different nodes simultaneously, I can do this using nested updated but that is long procedure...